# Filtering through a foreach function

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am pulling my hair out here, I simply cannot get this to work.

I need to do a foreach loop to get all authors in a website, I then need to filter the ones with 0 published articles out and then echo the authors with articles into a UL LI with a special

tag for the last author in the array:

My code at the moment has two functions, one to prefilter all authors that have at least one article and then in the second function count the number of authors left in the filtered array to then give the last entry in the array a special li tag. Code so far:

```
/*********************
    Echo Filtered List
    *********************/
    function filtered_list() {
        $authors = get_users('orderby=nicename');
        $all_authors = array();
         if ( count_user_posts( $author->id ) >= 1 ) {
             return true;
        }

    }


    function contributors() {

    $i = 0;
    filtered_list();
    $len = count($all_authors);
    foreach ($all_authors as $author ) {
          if ( count_user_posts( $author->id ) >= 1 ) {
                if ($i == $len - 1) {
                    echo "<li class='author-last clearfix'>";}
                else {
                    echo "<li class='author clearfix'>";}
                $i++;
```

Comment: What exactly you trying to do ?  You question seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read through your code you would probably see why it doesn't work.

**First: Scopes**

Read about variable scopes in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Basically, a variable declared inside a function is only available inside that function, so `$all_authors` is null inside contributors() as it has never been initialized.

The `filtered_list` function should *return* a filtered list of authors, so you should loop, though `$authors` and add the author to `$all_authors` if, and only if she has 1 or more posts. After the loop, return the array.

Now you can get the filtered list by setting the return value of the fist function to the $all_authors in `contributors` (or better yet, just call them `$authors`).

Now you are ready to iterate over the list of authors and find their post. To do this, you need two loops. One for authors, and one for the posts.

```
foreach author in authors
    foreach post in author->posts
        if post is last post
            print special stuff
        else
            print normal stuff
        endif
    endforeach
endforeach
```

Hope this helps, and that you'll learn something from it. Point is: Read though your code line by line and explain to yourself what it does.

Comment: That was meant as an advice, I'm sorry if it sounded agressive. The scope isn't the only thing that is wrong. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Hi, it's okay, I appreciate your help. I do understand variable scopes, but I have been doing this for so many hours that I have tried moving code around and made it a real mess. Previously it was working fine except for one thing - I filtered the foreach loop and after that was done I couldn't quite get it to find the last entry in the loop to give it a special html tag, that's when tropuble really started.

Comment: ALMOST! But thanks to your code I managed to finally get there! Thanks ever so much. You set to return the array after one } too many, so I fixed that and I had to tweak the second function slightly to get it to work exactly as I need it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to mark it as solved (the checkmark).